# codesandbox react "require.context is not a function" when getting images folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codesandbox

I am trying to recreate my react project in codesandbox.io, which fetches a random image from a folder. I am trying to recreate that code with the line

```
//get images from folder
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const images = importAll(
  require.context("./images", false, /^\.\/.*$/, "sync")
);
```

but the `require.context` line causes this error in codesandbox:

```
TypeError
require.context is not a function
```

Here is my [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-firefly-nj05r0?file=/App.js), is there something about my dependencies (react, react-dom, react-scripts) or something wrong with how im trying to fetch these local files in this folder in codesandbox?

codesandbox package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React example starter project",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "starter"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.8",
    "typescript": "4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

//get images from folder
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const images = importAll(
  require.context("./images", false, /^\.\/.*$/, "sync")
);

export default function App() {
  function setImgColors() {
    console.log("setImgColors()");
    var randomImg = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length) + 0];
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setImgColors();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Show your local `package.json`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski updated my question to include

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: yes, let me check my local versions package.json, but it works locally just fine, only issue is with this codesandbox site

Comment: I've never seen `require.context` in a react project. I would stick to the [official documentation of cra](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)